# Some HTML attributes are not working in email.(border, cellspacing...)

Tags: email, outlook

[Here's an email template with HTML.](http://dev.corp.doosan.com/doosaninfracore/newsletter.html)

And I tried to copy it in web browswer and paste in Outlook 2007.

But it looks different because `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` doesn't work in email.

For the worse, it varies from the each email system(Outlook, Gmail, hanmail...).

Is there any way to work HTML perfectly in every email system?

Thanks, always.

=======================

This is what it should be.
[image]

And this is from DAUM Hanmail,
[image]

and Gmail.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, Html Email has its pros and cons, and these might even vary with the email client too.

Here are some known limitations (some might nolonger be true though):

1. Large email bodies may not be sent to NotifyLink devices as HTML when Smart Retrieval is enabled (NotifyLink Enterprise Server: Contol Option Rules) or the body size is set to a limit that does not accommodate the email body size.  The email will sent in plain text.
2. Forwarding an HTML email from the device results in the forwarded email showing the original message twice, once in plain text and once in HTML format, when viewed on Oracle Beehive v1.5.x, Scalix, Sun, and Zimbra mail servers.
3. Using the Retrieve or Retrieve All options will not retrieve a full HTML picture email.  This may be due to a bug with the BlackBerry OS v5.0.
4. An HTML message viewed on the device that includes a phone number will not allow the phone number to be selected for dialing.
5. The bodies of messages sent using ActiveSync's SmartForward or SmartReply commands will always be in plain text format.
6. Body text that has been copied and pasted from a MS Word document into emails sent to the device in HTML format are cut off when the email has been sent from a Kerio mail server.

Read more here...

[How to Code Html Email correctly](http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/)

[And More Here...](http://www.sitepoint.com/email-rich-media-right-way/)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that not all email clients render HTML emails in the same way. Even between different version of Microsoft Outlook there are several differences.

Answer (score 1):

You may find interesting the next article
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
Hope this helps.